# Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

hi I am getting this warning and I want this warning to be solved and wouldn't be displayed on the console tab so I could upload my code to netlify and as far as I have read the documentation and policies of netlify, it says warnings and errors may be the reason that it can't be uploaded so I need this to be solved

index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-browser-router';
import "../src/assets/css/index.scss";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "daryaft-yar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-browser-router": "^2.1.2",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Shop from './Components/shop-bot/shop';
import Home from './Components/shop-bot/botHome';
import Coin from './Components/Coin/coin';
import Wallet from './Components/Wallet/wallet';
import AddCoin from './Components/AddCoin/add-coin';
import Cart from './Components/cart/cart';
import FinalCart from './Components/final-cart/final-cart';
import UserForm from './Components/user-from/user-form';
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Switch >
          <Route path="/bot/shop" component={Shop}/>
          <Route path="/bot/home"  component={Home} />
          <Route path="/bot/coin"  component={Coin} />
          <Route path="/bot/buy-coin"  component={AddCoin} />
          <Route path="/bot/wallet" component={Wallet} />
          <Route path="/bot/cart" component={Cart} />
          <Route path="/bot/cart-final" component={FinalCart} />
          <Route path="/bot/user-data" component={UserForm} />
          <Redirect from="/" exact to="/bot/shop" />
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: The warning seems pretty straight forward in informing you want needs to be changed. Have you tried applying the fix to your code? Can you edit the post to provide a complete [mcve] of the relevant code that is producing the warning?

Comment: I haven't used the methods mentioned in my code and I don't have clue how to do as the warning tells me

Comment: Is there any sort of code stacktrace you can share?

Comment: unfortunately, no there isn't

Comment: Well, unfortunately it is rather difficult to help diagnose code we can't see. Can you share how you are using `react-router-dom` and setting up your router and routes?

Comment: I'm using the `<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>` in the index.js file and the app.js I am using `<Switch >` and multiple `<Route />` components

Comment: Please add relevant code examples to your post instead of in the comments, formatting works so much better for readability in the post vs comments. It looks like you are using `react-router-dom@5`. Can you share also your package.json file in the post?

Comment: it's done as you said , I've shared the app.js , package.json and the app.js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be honest, `"react-browser-router": "^2.1.2",` in the package.json file seems like a mistake.

1. I don't think it's necessary
2. You are missing `react-router-dom` as a dependency.

I suggest uninstalling `react-browser-router` and installing `react-router-dom@5` so the `Switch` and `Redirect` components can still be imported. Installing the latest RRDv5 is important since there are potential issues with `react@18` and the `React.StrictMode` component and RRDv5 versions *below* v5.3.3, and if you ***don't*** specify v5 then the latest v6 version will be installed which has a lot of breaking changes.

From the terminal in the root project directory run:

```
npm uninstall --save react-browser-router
npm install --save react-router-dom@5
```

Update the `index.js` file to import the `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import "../src/assets/css/index.scss";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

From here you should restart the app locally to ensure all is well and working before deploying the app again.